# How to delete whole data flow in OpenMTC and Orion Context Broker

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

How can I delete whole data flow at once?

[image]

If an actuator is created in OpenMTC (container and instance), an event is triggered at the orion context broker app. The app will create an entity of the actuator on the Orion Context Broker with an attribute "cmd". After that a subscription to the attribute "cmd" is created and therefore all change on this attribute will be forwarded to the corresponding OpenMTC backend or gateway.

More details: https://github.com/OpenMTC/OpenMTC/tree/master/apps/OrionContextBroker

Answer (score 1):

Can you please tell me what you mean with deleting the whole data flow at once? I guess you do not want some of the operations. But there is no config option to disable the actuating.

You can either prevent the creation of the resource or use different labels for the resources that shall not mapped to the OCB.